# Underlying components of Node - toObject() producing different results on similar installations

Tags: node.js, redhat, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two installations of RedHat 6.7.

I installed them at different times, and they have different sets of packages (will post it later if possible).

With the same installation of node and npm, an identical node script acts completely different with toObject() and a complex object.

node v4.2.3
npm 2.14.7

On one, which is on a virtual machine, it does not need toObject() with a sub-object in the nodeJS script code to function correctly and ends up throwing an error.

The other will throw the error and not interpret that part of the object without it.

My two relevant questions:

If somehow one of the installations has an old node or npm on it, that wasn't removed completely or something, which one and what version?

Or is there some Linux package that could be overriding something in node?

Comment: You may need to be more specific, since I don't believe `toObject` is a native node function. Are you using `mongoose`? Are your `mongoose` versions the same? Include some code. Operating system / linux packages should not be relevant, either way.

Comment: That may be it- I am using a framework built on top of nodeJS called Strongloop Loopback. It may use mongoose, perhaps somehow the versions are different then. I'll look into it.